# Post request stops working

Tags: javascript, express, server, timeout

Im new to expressjs and server-scripting, but I've managed to create a simple server. But when I request to many times in a row, the server just stops responding. What could be the cause of this? Is there some timeout setting?

Server side:

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
});
```

Client side:

```
$(".post").click(function(){
   var obj = {};
   obj[$(this).attr("id")] = "roo";
   $.post("/test", obj);
});
```

It stops working after 6 requests. Whats going on?

Comment: Check the url in the network console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modify code with `res.end` you might see the difference.

That's possibly because you didn't response for the HTTP request, it becomes "pending requests". and browsers usually only cached for several requests (exactly 5 for Chrome)

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
    res.end("");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work adding just res.end, but res.end("") worked perfectly!